# Is it possible to modify existing solutions/templates?

Tags: 2010, site-template, solution-package

I modified the master page of a site and I would like to make all new sites that get created to use this master page by default. Is there a way to modify the built in site templates to use this master page by default using SharePoint 2010?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you suggest is actually going to break your warranty with Microsoft but there is a safe way of doing it.

You can use an event receiver for Site Provisioned / feature stapling, and set the master page in there for the new site.

Previous answer that should give you what you need to know: [Apply custom master for new site collection and sites under](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45231/apply-custom-master-for-new-site-collection-and-sites-under)

Comment: That's unfortunate that it's such a hack to do this. Seems like something that people might want to do often. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: It's by design I'm afraid, Microsoft don't want it made easy!